# How to Recover Data From Dead Screen Phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung

In an accident I got my Samsung Galaxy S3 broken. Mobile is turn on but screen is not working. I want some very important data from internal storage. Is there anyway to recover that data?

Comment: You can simply connect it to PC and transfer files via USB (MTP mode)?

Comment: This won't work if the device is locked.

Comment: How can I connect to MTP mode when screen is not displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Developer Settings are enabled and the device is rooted, you can plug the device into your computer via USB and use [androidscreencast](https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) to control the device and upload the files to an online storage service such as Google Drive before downloading the files on your computer.

Comment: Developer Setting ( Debugging Mode) ??

Comment: Sorry, yes: by "Developer Settings" I meant USB Debugging. Even if the device is not rooted, you can still use the computer to see your device's display.

Comment: and what about if debugging mode is not enable but phone is rooted?

Comment: Then you're pretty much out of options, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0):

If your computer can still recognize your phone when you plug it in, you can use this [android file manager](http://www.reviewstown.com/android-file-manager.html) to export the data from your phone to computer.